# Will my pictures be erased if I restart my iPod?

Tags: ipod

I need to know if my pictures are going to be erased if I restart my iPod.

Comment: Do you mean restart as in hold down the start button until iOS reboots or do you mean reset if through iTunes or have it recognized on a different iTunes?

Comment: You need to explain more about what you mean by restart.

Answer (score 3):

Only restarting you iPod will not erase your pictures. But for your Convenience you can plugin in you iPod on your computer or mac and make a backup with iTunes.

It you reset your iPod than your data will be lost. So make a backup with iTunes before.